# How to set a cron job to run at a exact date and time frame?

Tags: cron, cron-task

How can I set a cron to run every 30 mins between 8 am and 5 pm during the weekedays , here is my code but seems it not working

```
*/30 8-16 * * 1,2,3,4,5 cd /root/Desktop; ./script.sh
```

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ==>

**For Weekday**

```
*/30 08-17 * * 1-5 /path_of_file
```

**For Weekend** // Saturday, sunday

```
*/30 08-17 * * 0,6 /path_of_file
```

*/30 for every half hour

08-17 for 8 AM to 5 PM

1-5 for Monday to friday

0,6 For Sunday and Saturday